# How to use GSL with Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, gsl

I'm having issues trying to get GSL (GNU Scientific Library) to work with VS Express 2012.

I've downloaded a few different versions of the pre-compiled version of GSL, and changed my Includes/Linker settings in VS, but I haven't had much luck making it work properly. If anyone could help, I'd be eternally grateful as I've spent hours trying to figure this out by myself, and using internet resources to no avail!

Many thanks,
James

Comment: Did you try with: http://gladman.plushost.co.uk/oldsite/computing/gnu_scientific_library.php?

Comment: I had a look at it, but I'm a bit of a newbie to programming and the instructions in the readme weren't entirely clear to me so I didn't want to try it in case I broke something...